# Assigning initial values using the with statement

Tags: javascript

The following works:

```
var Person = {};
Person.FirstName = '';
Person.LastName = '';
with (Person) {
    FirstName = 'Phillip',
    LastName = 'Senn';
}
log(Person);
```

But I want to remove lines 2-3.

Comment: Because I'm reading a book on JavaScript and I'm learning the language.

Comment: Then you should read about the pros and cons of `with`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with Because of these cons it is recommended to not use it and there is seldom a case where one really has to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
var Person = {FirstName:'Philip', LastName:'Senn'};
log(Person);
```

Comment: Hmmm.  My old school thinking is fighting to continue using the equal sign for assignment operations.